# Heroku still accessing old jobs in the queue and not using the updated code

Tags: python, heroku, botocore

I'm trying to build a python app on Heroku. I want to upload an excel file to via botocore to a bucket hosted on AWS, but I get the following error:

```
2020-11-19T20:21:20.616363+00:00 app[web.1]: botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

I modified the code to include the credentials, cleared the cache, restarted the dynos and then started the app again. Now, I get the following error (along with the credentials error described above):

```
2020-11-19T20:21:20.616193+00:00 app[web.1]: Started at: 2020-11-10 15:35:54.303420
2020-11-19T20:21:20.616295+00:00 app[web.1]: Ended at: 2020-11-10 15:35:57.484733
2020-11-19T20:21:20.616331+00:00 app[web.1]: Exception status: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I had 2 questions here:

1. Why is heroku not using the updated code?
2. Why is it still accessing an old job even when I've cleared the cache, restarted the dynos, etc.?

Any help would be much appreciated -Thanks!

Comment: When you say that you updated the code to include credentials, did you do it with ```os.environ['MY_KEY']```? If yes, did you add this environment variable inside the heroku app? Also, do you have automatic deployment set up from a github repo?

Comment: Thanks for answering the question @VaduvaMihaitaBogdan!

Yes, I have done both. To answer your question about automatic deployment - Yes, I have that setup too.

Answer (score 0):

So, the way around this problem was to remove the redistogo addon and re-add it using the following commands:

```
heroku addons:remove redistogo --confirm <app-name>
heroku addons:add redistogo
```

Heroku was now reading the correct code. I had to do this every time there was an error in my code. Once, all the errors in the code were sorted out, there was no need to do this.